# Hover effect setting text opacity as well

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide text and when you hover over an item the opacity goes to 0.5 and the text appears. However, what seems to be happening is that the text is also getting set to opacity 0.5.

I am using react if you are wondering about the syntax.

```
<div
    className="course_grid-item"
    style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${bgImg4})` }}
>
    <div className="grid_course-name">
        <h5>Title</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.course_grid-item {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    background: white;
    padding: 2rem;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.course_grid-item:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.grid_course-name {
    opacity: 0;
}

.course_grid-item:hover .grid_course-name {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `course_grid-item` is parent to `grid_course-name`.

Any filter applied on the parent affects the child:

```css
.course_grid-item {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background: url("https://cdn.static-economist.com/sites/default/files/images/print-edition/20170722_STP001_0.jpg");
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.course_grid-item:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.grid_course-name {
  opacity: 0;
}

.course_grid-item:hover .grid_course-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="course_grid-item">
  <div class="grid_course-name">
    <h5>Title</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You could set the background image to `::before` instead:

```css
.course_grid-item {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: calc(100vw - 6rem);
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 5px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.course_grid-item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("https://cdn.static-economist.com/sites/default/files/images/print-edition/20170722_STP001_0.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.course_grid-item:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.grid_course-name {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}

.course_grid-item:hover .grid_course-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="course_grid-item">
  <div class="grid_course-name">
    <h5>Title</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or, have the image separate:

```css
.course_grid-item {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100vw - (4rem + 10px));
  margin: 4px auto;
}

.grid_course-background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background: url("https://cdn.static-economist.com/sites/default/files/images/print-edition/20170722_STP001_0.jpg");
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.course_grid-item:hover .grid_course-background {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.grid_course-name {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}

.course_grid-item:hover .grid_course-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="course_grid-item">
  <div class="grid_course-background"></div>
  <div class="grid_course-name">
    <h5>Title</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I overcome this then because I need the text inside of the item?

Comment: @Waterfall wrap the text in a generic `<span>` tag and apply CSS rules to that span tag element

Comment: I like your last example with the separate image. Just a question though, is it okay to use a background image or would it better to use an image in an `<img>` tag?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights, I have just realised that in your examples the text actually changes opacity after the image does

Comment: An image would work as well. Not sure why it does that, think it's just a browser quirk

Comment: `position: relative` seems to fix it

Comment: Hmm, I want to use your 3rd example but I don't think it is working. The text also seems to have an opacity of less than 1

Comment: Try setting it to `position: relative`, it works in both examples for me

Comment: @Daniel_Knights, ah yes. You are right. The is only one problem left now, and that is if you hover over the text itself, the overlay of the image goes away.

Comment: I think I fixed it by doing this `.course_grid-item:hover .grid_course-background {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }`

Comment: Oh yep, added that to my snippet